# App is showing in iphone's AppStore but not shwing in ipad's AppStore

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have app on AppStore. My app is showing in iPhone's AppStore but not showing in iPad's Appstore. Can anyone tell me why this happen?
Please help...

Comment: Is your app an iPhone-only app or a Universal app?

Comment: In my general settings -> Deployment info -> Devices, iPhone is selected instead of universal

Comment: no worries. just change to Universal in Xcode and again upload  build to iTunes Connect and submit for review

Comment: @Sanjuju You forgot to mention the really important part about thoroughly testing the app on iPads first to make sure the user interface looks and works properly on the larger screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select universal on devices settings. Please refer the screenshot [image]

Answer (score 0):

Choose **universal** device in your general setting of app then resubmit your app and also choose iPad in itunesconnect with its required screen shots.